# Why Cannot find my own custom module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I published my own npm module but it cannot find from my sample script.

This is my module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kong-hmac

https://github.com/y-zono/kong-hmac-js

What I did.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/sample-myjs
$ cd /tmp/sample-myjs/
$ touch package.json
$ echo "{}" > package.json
$ npm install --save kong-hmac
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
$ touch test.js
$ echo 'const hmac = require("kong-hmac");' > test.js
$ babel-node --presets es2015 test.js 
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'kong-hmac'
```

Any ideas? My module is written in ES2015.

Comment: i figured out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `node_modules` look for the package `kong-hmac` you find `lib` folder not `src` and in the `package.json` of kong-hmac change `"main": "src/index.js"` to `"main": "lib/index.js"`.

I guess, while publish a package npm structures the program this way

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing it now.

Comment: It worked. You are completely right. Thank you. You saved me!

Comment: Cool. I'll use it as a reference